# Why is my Clojure implementation of an LDAP paged results function not working?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

TLDR; this is not a well-phrased question, so you should probably not bother with it. I'll delete it in the near future unless people think it has some redeeming feature other than being a good example of how not to ask a question on Stack Overflow.

I am using the UnboundID LDAP SDK for one of my projects. I'm currently stuck on implementing a paged results search (described in RFC2696), for which I have a working Java implementation. I have tested the Java code, and know it works correctly against my test LDAP directory. The main part of the Java implementation is the following do..while loop:

```
do
{
  /*
   * Set the simple paged results control (if the cookie is null
   * this indicates the first time through the loop).
   */
  final SimplePagedResultsControl simplePagedResultsRequestControl =
      new SimplePagedResultsControl(pageSize,cookie);
  searchRequest.setControls(simplePagedResultsRequestControl);

  /*
   * Issue the search request:
   */
  SearchResult searchResult;
  searchResult = ldapConnection.search(searchRequest);
  final String msg =
      String
          .format(
              "searchRequest transmitted, pageSize: %d, entries returned: %d",
              Integer.valueOf(pageSize),
              Integer.valueOf(searchResult.getEntryCount()));
  final LogRecord record = new LogRecord(Level.INFO,msg);
  ldapCommandLineTool.out(new MinimalLogFormatter().format(record));
  total += searchResult.getEntryCount();
  /*
   * Get the cookie from the paged results control.
   */
  cookie = null;
  final SimplePagedResultsControl c =
      SimplePagedResultsControl.get(searchResult);
  if(c != null)
  {
    cookie = c.getCookie();
  }
}
while(cookie != null && cookie.getValueLength() > 0);
```

A request "control" is added to the search request indicating to the server that it should send back a subset of matching entries. Assuming the initial request is valid, the LDAP server returns pageSize entries and a response control containing a special "cookie". To get the next "page" of results the client re-sends the request, with the cookie included in the request control, and the server includes a new cookie with the subsequent response. This cycle continues until there are no more entries to return, in which case no cookie is returned to the client and the search request is complete.

I have attempted to port the above code to Clojure, but so far I have been unable to get it to work. Here's the code:

```
(defn fetch-all
  [& attrs]
  (with-connection
    (let [attrs (into-array (if attrs (map name attrs) ["*"]))
          scope SearchScope/SUB
          request (SearchRequest. searchbase scope account-filter attrs)]
      (loop [results [] cookie nil]
        (let [control [(SimplePagedResultsControl. page-size cookie)]]
          (doto request
            (.setSizeLimit 12345)
            (.setTimeLimitSeconds 60)
            (.setControls control))
          (let [result (.search *conn* request)
                results (concat result results)
                cookie (.. SimplePagedResultsControl (get result) getCookie)]
            (println "entries returned:" (.getEntryCount result))
            (when-not (> 0 (.getValueLength cookie))
              results
              (recur
               results cookie))))))))
```

The Java code retrieves 1720 entries with 18 requests, but mine fails with a "size limit exeeded" LDAPSearchException after five requests.

My question to you folks is why do the two implementations behave differently? I know that I'm sending the received cookie with each new request as an exception is thrown if the same cookie is used twice. I also think I know that I am getting subsequent pages of results, because the set of entries returned with each page is different.

I'm stumped, and not relishing the thought of dragging out Ettercap to analyse the traffic. Surely there's something very obviously wrong in my code which is causing the different behaviour.

Comment: This question really doesn't have anything to do with implementing do-while in clojure.  You have a conditional recur after the body of a loop; that's all you need to implement do-while.

Comment: There may be something very obviously wrong with your code, but there is too much code for anyone to enjoy reading and comparing it line by line for fun. Perhaps you should try a simple, minimal example and see if you understand the basic concept, or edit the question with your own piecewise analysis of the code for others to critique. As it is this is too painful a question to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. I've not much experience with Stack Overflow, and appreciate the candid feedback regarding the quality of my question. I'll have another stab at it.

Comment: I've solved the issue and will self-answer when I'm allowed in 3 hours :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, two bugs, and a gotcha in the RFC:

- (bug) the concatenation of the result to results should have been (concat (.getSearchEntries result) results),
- (bug) the 'when-not' test at the bottom of the loop should have been an 'if' or 'if-not'.
- (gotcha) under section 6 of the RFC, "Security Considerations", it is suggested that "Servers implementations may enforce an overriding sizelimit", which is to say that as a non-privileged user I will still hit the limit, paged results or not. The difference in behaviour between implementations was simply due to me running the Java code with administrative privileges and the Clojure code anonymously (doh!).

Answer (score 1):

`(let [control [(SimplePagedResultsControl. page-size cookie)]]`

Bind control to a vector of a single results control object.
This vector is then passed to

`(.setControls control)`

which seems to take a single results control object and not a vector as par your java code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ankur, that confused me to. I was getting a no matching method error with the control "unboxed". According to the SDK docs the method signatures for setControls are "setControls(Control... controls)" and "setControls(java.util.List<Control> controls". I was informed that (Control... controls) was Java slang for a list. I presume the Java compiler does the required cast for the bare Control argument, whereas Clojure requires it explicitly.